# Get Null and Not Null with condition Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$query = Attendance::query();
...
$query->whereNull('checkout_at')
    ->orWhereDate('checkout_at','>=',date('Y-m-d')->get();

return $query;
```

I want get all data with checkout `null`, but while it not null, query have a clause

Comment: orWhereDate`s closing bracket is missing, besides, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is fine (minus the missing parenthesis syntax error). However, it would be best to group the or'd conditions in case you want to add any other conditions to the query. Put your where conditions on the date inside a closure to group them:

```
$query
    ->where(function ($query) {
        return $query
            ->whereNull('checkout_at')
            ->orWhereDate('checkout_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d'));
    }
    ->get();
```